# How to replicate the Handbrake and DVD43 combination on 64 bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, handbrake

I recently upgraded my pc to windows 7. On my old 32bit machine I used to be able to run DVD43 in the background and use Handbrake to rip a DVD into iPhone format? DVD43 doesn't work on Windows 7 64 bit. So what's the best way to rip the DVDs I want into iPhone format on my Windows 7 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked around things like this by using Xp Mode.  Just install the software in 32bit Xp Mode and, if necessary, transfer control of any hardware to Xp Mode.  Sometimes Xp Mode needs exclusive access to the hardware.  For example, I used Xp Mode to install a 32bit printer driver and access an old printer:
http://aaronls.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/no-windows-7-driver-for-your-printer-use-xp-mode/

If you don't have an edition of Windows 7 that support Xp Mode, you can just use VirtualPC.

Comment: When I try to run DVD43 in xp mode it tells me that dvd43 is not supported on 64 bit windows. So I cannot even run it.

Comment: Run XP Mode in Virtual PC, and in the virtual PC window Right Click My Computer->Properties and under the general tab in the top section it should just say "Microsoft Windows XP Professional".  If it mentions anything about "x64 Edition" in the system Properties, then you have the wrong edition of Windows installed in the Virtual PC.

Comment: How do I "transfer hardware control to xp mode"? I am thinking I should hand over my blu-ray drive's control to xp mode while ripping.

Comment: You only need to do that if it's a USB device, in which case there will be a USB menu at the top of the XP Mode window.  Otherwise just access the drive as you normally would through My Computer or what have you.

Answer (score 7):

I went with [DVDDecrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/).  Although it does not work exactly the same way that DVD43 does because it does not allow Handbrake to rip directly from the DVD.  Instead, I used DVDDecrypter to rip the DVD to a folder on one of the disk drives, and Handbrake was able to successfully read the ripped folder.

Although it is not the perfect "DVD43 Experience", it is a freeware solution for anyone who does not want to use XP Mode.

Answer (score 6):

You can use handbrake with VLC's libdvdcss (free) in windows 64 bit (it's 32-bit but seems to work fine).
https://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16670#p78021

update: "Second, they tell you to rename libdvdcss-2.dll by removing the '-2' from the filename. This no longer works." (just leave it named the same these days apparently) ref: http://grandiloquentmusings.blogspot.com/2014/12/ripping-encrypted-dvds-with-handbrake.html

Comment: Interesting. XMBC also includes libdvdcss-2.dll and it is easier to get at without installing the thing. You can use 7zip to extract it from the installer exe.

Answer (score 2):

[SlySoft AnyDVD](http://www.slysoft.com) will transparently decrypt DVDs on the fly and some other cool things. It works well with Handbrake. However, it is not free.

Comment: Interesting that every time this gets upvoted, someone comes along and downvotes. What's the agenda?

Answer (score 0):

DVDFab does work in x64, and that will do a DVD9 to DVD5 conversion (folders or ISO) in the free version.  Granted, you have to do them one at a time.  There's also AnyDVD for the background process as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

A free alternative is [passkey for DVD](http://www.dvdfab.com/passkey-for-dvd.htm).  It is the free version of DVDFab, and it's working very nicely on a windows 7 install in place of an old handbrake+dvd43 setup I used to have.

Comment: Free?  I don't think so.  "Buy Now Price: $40.00"

Comment: @Heptite There's also a free version